# Filling in table values from neighbour rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that has a integer timestamp field from when the row was inserted but a bug in the inserting software left some of them as 0.
Only roughly 80% of the rows in the table has a valid timestamp.
It is not essential data so "faking" a timestamp is good enough to fix the table.

Since all rows are inserted in sequence it would make sense to set the timestamp of the row to the last row with a value of != 0

What kind of query can "fill the gaps" for 100.000 rows without taking forever?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the wanted result - as well formatted text.

Comment: do you have autoincremental `id` column?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have an ID that has AUTO_INCREMENT on it. In that case you could use the following type of code.

1. First create a temporary table, because you cannot insert into a table, with data querying that same table
2. Insert data into the temporary table
3. Update data in the first table
4. delete temporary table

I am not sure about you structure, but try something like the following

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_table` (id int NOT NULL PRIMARY_KEY, `timestamp` int NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO `temp_table` (`id`, `timestamp`)
    SELECT a.id, MAX(b.`timestamp`)
    FROM `your_table` a
    LEFT JOIN `your_table` b
    ON b.`id` < a.`id`
    WHERE a.`timestamp` = 0 AND b.`timestamp` != 0
    GROUP BY a.`id`;

UPDATE `your_table` a
INNER JOIN `temp_table` b
ON b.`id` = a.`id`
SET a.`timestamp` = b.timestamp;

DROP TABLE `temp_table` ;
```

Also don't know how fast it will be, I assume it will run in decent time